# Trying to make individual profile pages appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to make a Facebook-type site on Ruby on Rails 4 using devise. One of the features i'm trying to implement is an individual profile page, where you can go to a specific URL for a person's username and see that user's statuses.

Initially, the relevant code in my /app/views/profiles/show.html.erb file was this:

```
<% if @statuses %>
    <% statuses.each do |status| %>
        <div class="well">
            <% status.content %>
            <hr />
```

Which gave me a NameError in Profiles#show. Somewhere else, a person suggested that I change `statuses.each do` in the second line to `@statuses.each do` . At this point, the individual profile page now loads, but it still shows the statuses of one particular user no matter what. In other words, if I have a user called **nancydrew**, a user called **britneyspears**, and a user called **nickiminaj**, going to "/britneyspears" or "/nickiminaj" will still show nancydrew's statuses (instead of britneyspears' or nickiminaj's respective statuses). Visiting "/nancydrew" works as expected.

Here's a link to my github repository:

https://github.com/yamilethmedina/wheels_registration

And the rails server is currently running if you would like to see it in action:

https://wheels-registration-yamilethmedina.c9.io/

Comment: Looking at your server logs, what parameter is being sent in the get request for profile/show?

Comment: @JamesDullaghan I get a blank nancydrew page with this `Started GET "/britneyspears" for 12.43.117.2 at 2015-04-08 20:19:42 +0000
Processing by ProfilesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"britneyspears"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."profile_name" IS NULL  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Status Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "statuses".* FROM "statuses"  WHERE "statuses"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered profiles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (3.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 144ms (Views: 135.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables in the top answer are a little off and a few little things.

#### routes.rb

```
get '/:profile_name', to: 'profiles#show', as: :profile
```

Added `as: :profile` you can get to it with,

```
=link_to 'John Doe', profile_path(@user)
```

#### profiles_controller.rb

It shouldn't need to be any more complicated than this a for the moment.

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show]

  def show
    if @user
      render action: :show
    else
      render file: "public/404", status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = User.where(profile_name: params[:profile_name]).first
  end

end
```

#### profiles/show.html.erb

```
<div class ="page-header">
    <h1><%= @user.full_name %></h1>
</div>

<% if @user.statuses.any? %>
  <% @user.statuses.each do |status| %>
    <div class="well">
      <% status.content %>
      <hr />
      <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at), status_path(status) %> ago
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

#### registrations_controller.rb

You had forgotten to whitelist the profile name for users.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:profile_name, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:profile_name, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm currently having another issue (individual statuses won't show up on these profile pages), but this problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you have 2 routes being defined for profile#show

The first route is overriding the second route, which is the one you're looking to utilize in your controller method.

Delete the top profile#show definition

The profile route param should be explanatory of what it is for. Change :id to :profile_name or whatever attribute you're passing.

```
get "/:profile_name", to: "profiles#show"
```

Profile controller can be cleaned up considerably

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if user
      render action: :show
    else
      render file: "public/404", status: 404, formats: [:html]
    end
  end

  private

  def user
    User.find_by(profile_name: params[:profile_name])
  end

  def statuses
    user.statuses
  end

  helper_method :user, :statuses
end
```

And your view can use helper methods instead of littered instance variables per action.

```
<div class ="page-header">
    <h1><%= user.full_name %></h1>
</div>

<% if statuses.any? %>
  <% statuses.each do |status| %>
    <div class="well">
      <% status.content %>
      <hr />
      <%= link_to time_ago_in_words(status.created_at), status_path(status) %> ago
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: When I applied all of the changes that have been suggested (including those to routes.rb), I get a routing error that says "No route matches [GET]" , although I have a profiles_show_path present when I rake routes.

Comment: and you made sure to remove the conflicting profile#show route at the top of the route file? I cloned your repo down and it's working fine. I'll submit a PR for you. And you are visiting your url:port/profile_name, right?

Comment: i'm visiting the c9.io I linked above without a particular port. i'm working in their IDE, which was recommended to me since i'm a Windows user and I had too many issues installing Ruby and Rails on my PC. I'm not sure if that would make a difference, although all the server logs seem to believe that it's an ubuntu/linux server (as expected).

Comment: also, I haven't committed these most recent suggestions to github, because I was testing them and these new errors popped up. What's there now is the original code from when I initially asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, you have it set up as

```
get "/:id", to: "profiles#show"
```

which means in your controller, you need to use `params[:id]` instead of `params[:user_id]`. Also, if you're going to be using /britneyspears, /nickiminaj, etc, it makes more sense to call these profile_name under profile, so something like

```
get "/profile/:profile_name", to: "profiles#show"
```

and

```
@user = User.where(profile_name: params[:profile_name]).limit(1).first
```

Comment: When I did this, it says `"No route matches [GET] "/nancydrew"`, but when I remove the first `"/profile/"` from the `get "profile/:profile_name", to "profiles:show"`, it gives me a 404 page that says "The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."

Comment: This is the log I get in the latter situation: `Started GET "/nancydrew" for 12.43.117.2 at 2015-04-10 18:49:13 +0000
Processing by ProfilesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"profile_name"=>"nancydrew"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."profile_name" = 'nancydrew'  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered public/404.html within layouts/application (0.2ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 231ms (Views: 215.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)` I know I have a user called nancydrew because I was seeing her statuses on all the profiles previously

Comment: When you use `get "profile/:profile_name", to: "profiles:show"` you need to type in your url `/profile/nancydrew`, which i recommend you use, instead of just `/nancydrew`. In your private user method, use this instead, `User.find_by(profile_name: params[:profile_name])`, you dont even need the `@user = `, and add `helper_method :user, :statuses` in the controller so that your view can use those methods